# Where are the CsharpRepl and the interactive shell are located in Mono for Win?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I installed Mono on Win7 and trying to find the apps outlined [here](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

But they don't mention where are they located and launched.

Any ideas on how to access them as a user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just Launch the Mono command line (it's on the start menu).

Then type

```
csharp
```

And off you go

The twist is that the command line shortcut sets a bunch of environment variables (notably PATH) so that the mono binaries *and batch script wrappers* (!) are being found.

Comment: Thanks but what about the interactive shell one? Does it exist on Win platform?

Comment: csharp _IS_ the interactive shell one. Mind you it does have problems (recovering from runtime errors, it seems to loose application state; don't think that occurs on linux, actually)

Comment: Thanks sehe. But in that link I posted, it says `A GUI version of this tool is called gsharp and is available when you install the mono-tools package:`, what app is that?

Comment: Errm.. I haven't seen the gui variant on windows. In fact, I haven't used that on linux (I just tried it: had to install mono-utils-guim but works nicely on linux).

Comment: Ok, just tried. On Win7 64bit, mono 2.10.1 Build 2, starting "Mono-2.10.1 Command Prompt" from the start menu, typed `gsharp` (Enter) --> profit! Does it not work for you?

Comment: Thanks man, I just tried it with Mono 2.10.5 command prompt and it says 'gsharp' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: @Joan: I've little further advice other than to brute-force search it (Win+F to find files or if you prefer `DIR /S /B C:\gsharp.*` or in that vein... I clearly ought to work, so if something is missing from the installer, verify by repear/reinstall and optionally file a bug http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Answer (score 3):

It's the `csharp.bat` file in the `bin` directory, along with mono.exe etc.

Having put the `bin` directory in your path, you should just be able to run `csharp` from a command line and get straight in. That's certainly the case with Mono 2.10.5, which I've just installed.

Comment: Thanks but what about the interactive shell one? Does it exist on Win platform?

Comment: @Joan: That *is* the interactive shell.